# Exclude files in war file myeclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, myeclipse

How to exclude specific files (e.g., files in source folder src/test/java) while doing Export to WAR file?

I tried doing export to war in myeclipse, but it doesn't provide me any option to choose files to remove.

Comment: try `ANT` or `MAVEN` build process to customize the WAR file.

Comment: Thanks! yes, i can use MAVEN or ANT, i was checking if there was something provided by IDE like myeclipse for development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the WAR Project

Click on Properties==>Deployment Assembly. Here you can perform the add/remove/edit.

[image]